# File not reading textfile after running Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to write something that checks a specific service, puts that into a text file. Afterwords I am trying to determine if its stopped or running and do other things.

The file gets created and looks like this, I tried parsing this out individually or using `.readlines()` but no dice. Any helps/tips would be appreciated.

```
SERVICE_NAME: fax 
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

but my code below returns empty or nothing

```
from subprocess import Popen
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
squery = ['sc', 'query', 'fax']
proc = Popen(['sc', 'query', 'fax'], stdout=open(str(today.date())+'_ServiceCheck.txt', 'w'))
if 'STOPPED' in open(str(today.date())+'_ServiceCheck.txt').read():
    print("Uh Oh")
    #Do Something about it
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but `Popen` is non-blocking, so if you launch a subprocess that writes to file and your parent process immediately tries to read it, there's no guarantee the child will win the race. `subprocess.call` blocks and waits for the subprocess to finish before continuing execution. Do you want to poll the file periodically to check for "STOP"? Please clarify your intent.

Comment: I want to run this with another piece of python which uses selenium to check something on a webpage. If that piece fails It is going to log the datetime that it was stopped adding this check of the service. If its stopped then restart/start it.  Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: I see, yeah, it sounds like you need a loop. Add a `sleep` and periodically open the file to see if it contains `STOPPED`, then re-launch the process if it does.

Comment: Thats a decent idea, I should also check if the file exists already. I am betting it is overriding the file everytime its run even though its the same day. So If I check it first  before opening it I may get better results~

Comment: I wrote a general answer, but more details about what you're doing would help a lot, otherwise it's a bit unclear what sort of behavior is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, there's a good chance the parent process will open the file, check for `STOP` and close long before the subprocess even starts running. You can use `subprocess.call` to force the parent process to block until the child finishes executing, which might enable the idea of waiting for your Selenium script's process to finish execution.

Consider this:

```
# some_script.py
from time import sleep

print("subprocess running!")

for i in range(5):
    print("subprocess says %s" % i)
    sleep(1)

print("subprocess stopping!")
```

```
# main.py
import subprocess

while True:
    print("parent process starting child...")
    proc = subprocess.call(["python", "some_script.py"])
    print("parent process noticed child stopped running")
```

Output excerpt from running `python main.py`:

```
parent process starting child...
subprocess running!
subprocess says 0
subprocess says 1
subprocess says 2
subprocess says 3
subprocess says 4
subprocess stopping!
parent process noticed child stopped running
parent process starting child...
subprocess running!
subprocess says 0
subprocess says 1
subprocess says 2
subprocess says 3
subprocess says 4
subprocess stopping!
parent process noticed child stopped running
...
```

This seems much better. The parent blocks completely until the child stops execution, then immediately restarts the child.

Otherwise, to do what you're doing, it sounds like you'll need to poll the file periodically like:

```
import datetime
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

delay = 10

while True:
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    fname = '%s_ServiceCheck.txt' % today.date()

    file_content = open(fname).read()

    if 'STOPPED' in file_content:       
        print('Uh oh')     
        proc = Popen(['sc', 'query', 'fax'], stdout=open(fname, 'w'))

    sleep(delay)
```

But be careful--what if the Selenium process stops at 11:59:59? Polling this text file is pretty brittle, so this script is probably nowhere near robust enough to handle all cases. If you can redirect your Selenium script's output directly to the parent process, that would make it a lot more reliable. The parent process can also write the log to disk on behalf of the script if needed.

Either way, a lot of it depends on details about your environment and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you , I hadnt considered that it was doing it in such a fast way that it couldnt read it. I will use some of this logic to help me with this issue

Comment: Cool. Glad it was helpful.